# Fluent nhibernate hasmanytomany & adding it

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

i have used fluent nhibernate for 3projects so i know the basics but i havent used the hasManyToMany yet. i have found documents that show me how to mapp it so i guess that is ok. my question about that is what sould use the hasManyToMany in its mapping and what should i put in the other? let me know if im unclear in my explaining and if you need more info about the mappings.

Receiver,
Mail,
MailReceiver

then i wonder how i add that with nhibernate code in my code? my code go like this sofar.

var rService = ObjectFactory.GetInstance().GetById(id);
var MService = ObjectFactory.GetInstance().GetById(id);

//todo add the

thanks for helping a newbee :)

Answer (score 0):

i found a pretty good blogpost about this
http://marekblotny.blogspot.com/2009/02/fluent-nhbernate-and-collections.html